# Nested URLs in Sphinx

Tags: url, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Say I have two links in a `file.rst` :

```
.. _link1: https://link1.com
.. _link2: https://link1.com/val
```

Is there a way to use `link1` in `link2` like what I have below with custom display text for the user:

```
.. _link1: https://link1.com
.. _link2: link1/val
```

This is how I intend to use it:

```
See link `here <link1_>`_ for more details check `this <link2_>`_ out.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Sphinx extension [`extlinks`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html).

> This extension is meant to help with the common pattern of having many external links that point to URLs on one and the same site, e.g. links to bug trackers, version control web interfaces, or simply subpages in other websites. It does so by providing aliases to base URLs, so that you only need to give the subpage name when creating a link.

Comment: I have added more clarifications and an example usage. Not really sure if `extlinks` has a simple solution to this common problem. AFAIK if I was to do this using `extlinks` I would need to create new URLs every time for a new display text.